# How does PyCharm find libraries installed with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using `PyCharm` and also installing dependencies with `pip` I dont know how to make PyCharm to get this new dependencies that I install and are in the folder `{project_base}/env/lib/python3.9`

If I go there I can see the libraries installed, but PyCharm is not able to seen it, and allow me to use it in the code.

I've seen in the preference the `Python Interpreter` section, but I need to use pip, since I'm documenting the package to install with pip for other users.

Any idea how to point my PyCharm to my `env/lib/` folder?

Regards

Comment: Choose the venv as an interpreter and the libraries will be available to use.

Comment: Wrongly closed as duplicate, because the author specifically asks about the relationship between pip and PyCharm. Please do not be so trigger happy with your vote to close finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose `Python Interpreter`, PyCharm will automatically pick up libraries available on that Python installation.

Make sure PyCharm uses the Python Interpreter that has its libraries installed in `env/lib/python3.9` and then you should see available libraries on the interpreter configuration screen.

If you install libraries with pip e.g. `env/bin/python -m pip install mylib` they will become automatically available to PyCharm, because PyCharm and pip will use the same Python installation to manage these libraries.

Comment: Isn't this  duplicate?

Comment: This question was wrongly closed as duplicate, because the author specifically asks about the relationship between `pip` and PyCharm.

Comment: The question was correctly closed as duplicate. Because installing a package using pip in PyCharm is exactly what the duplicate target is about.